# How to make the space between cerain lines smaller

Tags: html, css

I am making a Website and I wondered how to make onle sapce between certain links smaller because I need some smaller some bigger.

Thanks in advance

```
 <a class="sub-btn">Aktionen<i class="fas fa-angle-right dropdown"></i></a>
            <div class="sub-menu">
         
               <a href="#" class="sub-item">Känguru der Mathematik</a>
               <a href="#" class="sub-item">Der EKS stellt sich vor</a>
               <a href="#" class="sub-item">101 neue FünftklässlerInnen</a>
               <a href="#" class="sub-item">Müllsammelaktion</a>
               <a href="#" class="sub-item">Tag der Handschrift</a>
               <a href="#" class="sub-item">Mathematikwettbewerb 2021 Runde 2</a>
               <a href="#" class="sub-item">Begrüßung der 5. Klässler</a>
               <a href="#" class="sub-item">Sommercamp 2022</a>
               <a href="#" class="sub-item">Ferien-/Tage</a>
               <a href="#" class="sub-item">Klassenrat</a>
               <a href="#" class="sub-item">Schülerparlament</a>
               <a href="#" class="sub-item">Leseförderung</a>
               <a href="#" class="sub-item">Beruforientierung</a>
               <a href="#" class="sub-item">Imagefilm</a>
               <a href="#" class="sub-item">Materialliste</a>
             </div>
```

Comment: Sorry if this was a bit misleading. English is not my native language. I meant the space between certain lines

Comment: Do you mean the [padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) of the different `sub-item` elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to specify which ones you want to make bigger and which one smaller, because it is important but in general, you can use pseudo selectors to make it happen:

```css
.sub-item {
  display: block;
}

.sub-item:is(:nth-child(2), :nth-child(3), :nth-child(6), :nth-child(11)) {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="sub-menu">
  <a href="#" class="sub-item">Känguru der Mathematik</a>
  <a href="#" class="sub-item">Der EKS stellt sich vor</a>
  <a href="#" class="sub-item">101 neue FünftklässlerInnen</a>
  <a href="#" class="sub-item">Müllsammelaktion</a>
  <a href="#" class="sub-item">Tag der Handschrift</a>
  <a href="#" class="sub-item">Mathematikwettbewerb 2021 Runde 2</a>
  <a href="#" class="sub-item">Begrüßung der 5. Klässler</a>
  <a href="#" class="sub-item">Sommercamp 2022</a>
  <a href="#" class="sub-item">Ferien-/Tage</a>
  <a href="#" class="sub-item">Klassenrat</a>
  <a href="#" class="sub-item">Schülerparlament</a>
  <a href="#" class="sub-item">Leseförderung</a>
  <a href="#" class="sub-item">Beruforientierung</a>
  <a href="#" class="sub-item">Imagefilm</a>
  <a href="#" class="sub-item">Materialliste</a>
</div>
```

Also, there are a lot of ways to do this, and this is one of them.
You can use **:where()** either.